# Where in the source code of the Core Client is the GetBlockValue() function?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I was reading Antonopoulos' book and there is a piece of code in chapter 8 in the part about Coinbase Reward and Fees and the code is a `GetBlockValue()` function. I was looking for it on github but didn't find it. I found something about a function called `GetBlockSubsidy()` that works in a similar way and is apparently a newer version but I can't find this one either. Also all the links I found linking to main.cpp in the repository don't work. Where is this part of the code now or what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetBlockValue` was [renamed](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/935bd0a447834fa48c218ddae2a5d835a67979ef) to `GetBlockSubsidy`, and `main.cpp` was [renamed](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/76faa3cdfedbd3fc91be4ecfff77fc6dc18134fb) to `validation.cpp`.  So you should now look at `GetBlockSubsidy` in `src/validation.cpp`.

You can search on Github for `GetBlockValue`; you won't find any hits in code but you will [find some in commits](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/search?q=GetBlockValue&type=Commits&utf8=%E2%9C%93).  That's how I found this.